# Accessing the number of times a variable is used in a HashMap?

Tags: java

I was wondering if there is any way to access the number of times a given variable is used in a HashMap.

Consider the following code:

```
public class HashMapTest {

public enum Sex {
    MALE, FEMALE;
}

private static HashMap<Integer, Sex> map = new HashMap();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    map.put(1, Sex.FEMALE);
    map.put(2, Sex.FEMALE);
    map.put(3, Sex.FEMALE);

    System.out.println("Female added. There are currently #NUMBER HERE females.");

}
}
```

In this code I'm setting 3 keys to female. is there a way to outprint the amount of Females are set?

Or am I better off using 2 seperate ArrayLists, one for male one for female?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Collections.frequency(map.values(), Sex.FEMALE)` will do the job.

Comment: Thanks didn't think of this.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is

```
map.values().stream().filter(Sex.FEMALE::equals).count()
```

This solution requires Java 8.